# How to create a grouped bar chart where bars within groups are organized in descending order?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a grouped bar chart showing the average tenure of four types of cabinet ministers (defense, agriculture, finance, and economy) across four autocratic regime subtypes (party, personal, military, and monarch). Here is the dataset:

```
structure(list(minister_type = c("Defense", "Finance", "Foreign Affairs", 
"Agriculture", "Defense", "Finance", "Foreign Affairs", "Agriculture", 
"Defense", "Foreign Affairs", "Finance", "Agriculture", "Defense", 
"Foreign Affairs", "Finance", "Agriculture"), regime_subtype = c("Military", 
"Military", "Military", "Military", "Monarch", "Monarch", "Monarch", 
"Monarch", "Party", "Party", "Party", "Party", "Personal", "Personal", 
"Personal", "Personal"), average_tenure = c(2.60493827160494, 
2.48979591836735, 2.33165829145729, 2.19170984455959, 5.94202898550725, 
4.20212765957447, 4.14772727272727, 3.35576923076923, 4.93292682926829, 
4.60164835164835, 3.91704035874439, 3.49769585253456, 3.46043165467626, 
2.99093655589124, 2.78651685393258, 2.57228915662651)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the code to produce the plot:

```
# Create the grouped bar plot
ggplot(sorted_df, aes(x = regime_subtype, y = average_tenure, fill = minister_type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = minister_colors) +
  labs(x = "Regime Subtype", y = "Average Tenure", fill = "Minister Type") +
  ggtitle("Average Tenure by Minister Type and Regime Subtype") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Here is the resulting plot:
[image]

What I want is for the bars to appear in descending order *within each group*. In other words, I want the minister with the longest tenure to be the first bar, next longest the second, and so on. I have been unable to get this to work. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Combinations of red and green are not a good idea as many people struggle to distinguish them.

Comment: Not the question, but a dot chart would work as well or better here. I guess most interest is on comparing means with each other, not with zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this task we add a group aesthetics and use `geom_col()` with `position_dodge2()`:

```
sorted_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = regime_subtype, y = average_tenure, group = regime_subtype, fill = minister_type)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2())+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")+
  labs(x = "Regime Subtype", y = "Average Tenure", fill = "Minister Type") +
  ggtitle("Average Tenure by Minister Type and Regime Subtype") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]